transfer session cookie to iframe by safari browser
I have problem with iframe tag in my project. safari by default block session cookie in iframe and I need transfer cookie to new website with different domain.
I rather choose best solution for this problem.
I add sandbox attribute(allow-same-origin) to iframe but doesn't work.
is there a way access without using postMessage api and rest service ?

Not possible. If you could access the cookies created on another domain it would be a massive security flaw.

You might have been able to do this in 2004. it is not possible today because of (among other security issues) XSS. If you want to share a session identifier you have to find a parameter or key that you can pass to the iframe site. if you are not the owner of the two domains and can tweak something, or send the iframe to an oauth2 provider for login, you should think of an alternative way to accomplish your goal
